# Angular firebase foreign key / ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase, crud

I have two tables in firebase `Departamentos` *-> parent* and `Ciudades` *-> child*. When I'm showing the cities in the `ng-repeat` view, I need replace the `$id` `Departamento` to the name in the `Departamentos` table. How can I do it?

---

Database:

[image: database]

---

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in ciudades | filter:search">
 <td>{{obj.idItem}}</td>
 <td>{{obj.nombreCiudad}}</td>
 <td>{{obj.departamentoEciudad }}</td> <-- replace the id to the name located in 'departamentos' table
</tr>
```

[image: view]

Comment: don't use screen shots when asking any question, better use a fiddle to get a good response.

Comment: One way would be to extend the `$firebaseArray` so that every time a city is added/modified, you look up its department. See this section of the AngularFire docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do another lookup to the Departamentos table using departamentoEciudad then add it to your ng-repeat object

```
$scope.ciudades.departamentoObj = $firebaseObject(rootRef.child(departamentoEciudad));

<td>{{obj.departamentoObj.nombreDepartamento }}</td>
```

Comment: Great, have you some link or documentation that help me, thanks.

Comment: From the AngularFire Documentation and some trial and error, https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html

Comment: You've most of the way there already with what you must of coded, you've got a nice denormalized data-model and your retrieving your data from one of the Nodes correctly

Comment: ReferenceError: departamentoEciudad is not defined

Comment: In my code departamentoEciudad is just a variable for $scope.ciudades.departamentoEciudad. My code is not complete, its dependent on what you've already coded which is hard to determine as you haven't posted your full code

Comment: Actually I think Im wrong, I said your data is denormalized correctly, ciudades > departamentos is a one to one relationship? To optimize your read performance you should have the data in the same Node

Answer (score 0):

I`m happy because this blocker is already solved, i did it:

I added a new field in database called -nombreDepartamento- and when the controller start with a foreach i do a query to replace the $id by departamentos.nombre :)

```
$scope.replaceRelated = function() {
    urlRefCiudad.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key(),
                refKey = new Firebase(urlItemCiudad+'/'+key);

            urlRefCiudad.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                var idDtoEciudad = snapshot.val()[key].departamentoEciudad,
                    urlDtoEciudad = urlRefDto.child(idDtoEciudad);

                urlDtoEciudad.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                    var nombreRelated = snapshot.val().nombreDepartamento;
                    console.log(nombreRelated);
                    refKey.update({ RnombreDepartamento: nombreRelated});
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```